# Meaning of 'why' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

In "A Song of Ice And Fire: A Game of Thrones," it says :

> "Stories wait, my little lord, and when you come back to them, **why**,
>   there they are."

I don't really understand the meaning of 'why' in this sentence.

Comment: This could be answered by looking up "why". One definition is: WHY (interjection) —used to express mild surprise, hesitation, approval, disapproval, or impatience

Answer (score 1):

The word "why" in this case could used like a word of exclamation. You could easily replace it with "WOW" or "Oh" and it would still make sense

also the author could have meant the word "why" to mean "in fact"

Comment: Hello, Mei. Notice that Pablo gave this in a 'comment', because OP could (and should) have looked up 'why' for themself.